# window functions not available mysql 8

Tags: mysql

```
mysql> SELECT VERSION()
    -> ;
+-----------+
| VERSION() |
+-----------+
| 8.0.27    |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.02 sec)

mysql> SELECT row_number() over w as 'row_number', prod_id FROM db.table WINDOW w;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WINDOW w' at line 1
```

Why doesn't this work and how can I get this query to work?

Comment: I don't think it is right syntax which you are using.

Comment: What is `WINDOW` doing after the table name?

Comment: See [named windows](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions-named-windows.html)

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't defining the window.. once I add the AS clause this works:

```
 SELECT row_number() over w as 'row_number',
   prod_id
 FROM db.table
 WINDOW w AS (order by prod_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use named window function.

`Named window` function are basically used when there are many window function being used and you are doing same `partition by` or `order by` in every over clause of `window`.
So named window function gives you relaxation or advantage to write `partition by /order by` once and have that named window in you `over` clause.

You probably need to implement below query for your case.

```
SELECT row_number() over w as 'row_number', prod_id FROM db.table WINDOW w as (order by prod_id);
```